# Loop for tabbing

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

HI i am pretty new to javascript,

following is my scenario, i want to make a function in which i pass the value of 'n' for number of iterations. i am writing my test script in javascript.

```
    var tab6 = browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.TAB);
    tab6.perform();
    page.pause(3);

    var tab7 = browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.TAB);
    tab7.perform();
    page.pause(3);

    var tab8 = browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.TAB);
    tab8.perform();
    page.pause(3);

    var tab9 = browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.TAB);
    tab9.perform();
    page.pause(3);

    var tab10 = browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.TAB);
    tab10.perform();
    page.pause(3);

    var tab11 = browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.TAB);
    tab11.perform();
    page.pause(3);
```

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding what it is you want.

Comment: Hi adam, i am trying for a function with for loop where i need to pass the value of n for number of iterations in the above i have to write same thing for 6 times.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want ?

```
function performTab(n) {
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    var tab = browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.TAB);
    tab.perform();
    page.pause(3);
  }
}
```

If not, please, be more precise.

Comment: Thanks for the loop, i need a function where i just need to pass the number for number of iterations.

Comment: i tired passing 5 but it is showing as syntax error: unexpected identifier          function performTab(5) {
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    var tab = browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.TAB);
    tab.perform();
    page.pause(3);
  }
}

Comment: sorry, my bad. int is for java. In javascript, we use var. Edited the answer, now it should work ^^

Comment: i am trying to pass the value of n as 5, its throwing syntax error: unexpected number eg: function performTab(5)

Comment: You really used the edited function above ? And you are sure the code in your question works ? It is really strange then

Comment: yes i used the edited function,and yes code in my question works.

Answer (score 0):

You want to count how many times you press tab, following a predetermined direction?

i'm really having a hardtime understanding what you want.

```
document.onkeypress = tabCount;
var ix = 0;
function tabCount(e){
    var charCode = (typeof event.which == "number") ? event.which : event.keyCode
    if (charCode == 9) ix++;
}

<input type=button tabIndex=1>
<input type=button tabIndex=2>
<input type=button tabIndex=3>
<input type=button tabIndex=4>
<input type=button tabIndex=5>
```

Answer (score 0):

in context of test scenario, I'd do:

```
function testTabs( n )
{
    for ( let i = 1; i <= n; i++ )
    {
        it(`Select tab #{i}`, () => {
            browser.actions().sendKeys( protractor.Key.TAB ).perform();
            page.pause(3);
        };
    };
}
```